# tExtractRegexField unable to act as lookup to tMap in Talend DI

Tags: talend, data-integration

I have a `tExtractRegexField` which extracts a date from a string of text coming from a `ExcelFileInput` and will output the dates to `tLogRow` but I can't connect the same output as a lookup column to a `tMap` with a 2nd `ExcelFileInput` as its main input.

If I connect the `ExtractRegexField` to `tMap` first I can't then connect the 2nd `ExcelFileInput` and vis versa

I'm  using Talend 6.3.1 and for testing I am able to connect 2 x `ExcelFileInput` to a `tMap` so I dont think its a problem with my system setup.
I have also tried `tJoin` instead of tMap but I encounter the same issue (can't connect both inputs together but can connect **"A"** or **"B"** first)

**Overview of Process**
[image: Overview of Process]
**Problem Area**
[image: Close up of problem area]
The tExcelFileInput uses globalMap to get the path to the excel file from the preceding tFlowToIterate

Comment: Seems to also affect me when chaining tMaps

Comment: works for me.  I want as far as also hooking up the FlowtoInterates preceding each excel and it still works.  Could be the replicate or something further back that your diagram does not show.  Try a sample job where you simply things and then keep adding components until you see what breaks it.

Comment: When I run the job I get the warning `Warning:  Cannot read name ranges for TableName - setting to empty` which disappears when I disable from tFilterRow. Is there a way to debug talend to see why its not creating the connection for me?

Comment: your losing me.  is the name ranges a 'Named Range' within Excel?

Comment: The filter row (offscreen) is filtering a list of .xls files to select the file names I need to process which feeds the tReplicate. The excel files do appear to have some named ranges and some macro code for formatting.   All that is more background information as its the only troubleshooting information I can access at the moment in Talend

Comment: I don't have enough info to help out further.  Maybe its just me and someone else will pipe in with help. Otherwise please update question with more comprehensive and clear info about the issue or open a new question.  If we go back to the beginning, I setup a job just like yours starting to the right of tReplicate and it worked fine.  Try it without the tReplicate (if possible) and see if that helps.  Or post diagram of entire job and I can see about setting that up to test and see if it allows me to hook both into one tMap (your original issue)

Comment: Added an overview of the process

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussions on the talend forum the issue may have been down to a desire by taland DI to avoid circular references

An alternative solution is to extract the regexfield from the header row and store them in a global variable using a `tJavaRow` and `globalMap.put("MyVal", row.Data);` and then `OnComponentOk` read the remaining data from the body rows and in the `tMap` recall the global variable `MyVal` and include it as needed in your `tMap` Output